# Change tags on numerous questions in one go

Tags: support, tags, edits

I feel like this must have been asked before but I can't find anything in the help or a similar question in meta.

Is there a mechanism for altering a tag from a large number of questions in one go?

The particular reason is, I've noticed when browsing questions relating to Apache Hue ([hue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hue)) that many of the questions (including the top-most popular ones) with this tag relate to questions concerning colour manipulation rather than the Apache product, which makes finding relevant questions arduous.  I would like to tidy this up but don't fancy editing each and every question long-hand.  I feel that in these cases the tag should be removed, or arguably changed to [colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colors).

Comment: There is not. And be careful when editing. The need for an edit like this indicates there may be another issue with the tag. Maybe the description is unclear or the name isn't specific enough. Better discuss that on meta before singlehandedly editing them all.

Comment: OK Thanks @Cerbrus - the [hue] tag is very clear and relates to the Apache product (but perhaps didn't historically).  Would you suggest a new meta question to discuss or a minor edit of this one?  Thanks

Comment: Also (especially if you're going to be editing many questions), please be sure to fix *everything* you can in each question, as each of your edits -- no matter how minor -- will require the time and attention of multiple reviewers.

Comment: I believe that moderators (or CMs?) do have the ability to do mass re-tagging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no user-visible functionality that allows to retag multiple questions.

Before attempting any mass edits (even if you plan just 5-10 of the same kind) make sure

- to discuss on meta what change actually needs to be made. In this case may be better route would be to rename [hue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hue) to [apache-hue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-hue) and review all questions
- to confirm again on meta if particular type of edit is recommended for users who can only suggest edits. Most likely doing mass re-tagging so all changes endup in edit review queue is a bad idea (queue will quickly fill up with such changes effectively blocking everyone else to propose changes)
- if discussions lead to "go ahead and cleanup" fix all issues with each post you've touched.

If number of incorrectly tagged questions is small (let's say less than 5) and change does not feel controversial (like in this case if tag's info specifies that it does not apply to color-related questions) you can proceed with editing posts to remove tag, but don't forget to fix all issues in each post you've touched. Consider voting on the questions - don't be afraid to downvote/vote to close instead of editing if questions are not appropriate for SO.